# How to add CKeditor Templates

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Using [CKeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module I am trying to add a new [template](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates).

I have modified `default.js` in

`\sites\all\modules\ckeditor\ckeditor\plugins\templates\templates\default.js`

By adding a new entry, however after Flushing caches/restarting web server, I still don't see the new template when I edit content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was hard to find the information but I succeed:

1. Copy `ckeditor.config.js` from the ckeditor module ( `sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/` ) to your theme ( `sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/` )
2. Edit the ckeditor profile configuration in Drupal ( `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full` ): in ADVANCE OPTION, set **Load ckeditor.config.js from the theme path** to YES
3. Modify the `ckeditor.config.js` from your theme to add your custom template file:

   `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {`

   config.templates_files = [ Drupal.settings.basePath +   'sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/js/ckeditor.custom.templates.js' ]; 
   //...continue the config file
4. Copy your image template to `sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/ckeditor-tpl/`
5. In your JS theme file ( `sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/js/` ) create a file `ckeditor.custom.templates.js` as following:

   `CKEDITOR.addTemplates( 'default',
   {
   imagesPath: CKEDITOR_BASEPATH + '../../themes/boson/ckeditor-tpl/' ,
   templates :
       [
           {
               title: 'My template',
               image: 'my-template.PNG',
               description: 'Your custom template.',
               html: 'Hello world!'
           },
       ]
   });`

it works well for me. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: for my set up, I left the ckeditor.config.js file as is and simply added the config option: " config.templates_files = [ Drupal.settings.basePath +   'sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/js/ckeditor.custom.templates.js' ]; " to the Custom Javascript Configuration textarea under Advanced Controls. Works perfectly, thanks for the guide.

Comment: Can't believe I've only just found this! Would have saved me so much time.Brilliant, thanks. Thanks @ymdahi too - this method is cleaner and allows ckeditor module to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you could just use the [Wysiwyg API template](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_template) module.  Here's a pretty [good tutorial on adding templates](http://www.inclind.com/journal/creating-custom-templates-in-drupal-7-wysiwyg-editor/) step-by-step.