# How do I allow editors to select a template with CkEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using CkEeditor to edit the node body field. I want to add a *Select template* option in CkEditor.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49500/how-to-add-ckeditor-templates

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a closer look at the widget API / the widget plugin for CKEditor. The widget API enables you to have something like 'templates' meaning predefined groups of elements inside the editor window.

> "*Widgets are **special rich content units** in that they are **groups of elements** which are **treated as a single entity** inside the editor.*"

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets

At the end of that page there are links to further info about the Widget SDK and a step-by-step tutorial for creating your own widget ('mini-template').

I use the widgets plugin myself together with the [SCALD module family](http://drupal.org/project/scald) and I must say I am still quite excited how very well these two play together.

If you 'just' want to add *content templates* however, you should probably download and install the [Content Templates](http://ckeditor.com/addon/templates) plugin for CKEditor.

From the download dialog window:

> *Extract the downloaded plugin .zip into the plugins folder of your CKEditor installation. Example:*
>
> *http://example.com/ckeditor/plugins/templates*
>
> *Enable the plugin by using the extraPlugins configuration setting. Example:*
>
> *config.extraPlugins = 'templates';*
>
> *Download and configure all its dependencies, too.*
>
> *Add-on Dependencies: [Dialog](http://ckeditor.com/addon/dialog)*

The configuration setting can be found/added in config.js inside the ckeditor directory.

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0404r4oxe2 
PLease check this. I need this.

Comment: oky, you'll probably want the Content Templates plugin for CKEditor. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have download and put it sites\all\modules\ckeditor\plugins\templates.. but it not showing on editor.http://awesomescreenshot.com/00f4r4wc62

Comment: where I need to use this code: config.extraPlugins = 'templates';

Comment: I fear this is getting beyond 'drupal' – but anyways: have you read and folloewd the install info? There are at least two addinitional steps necessary – I pasted them above..

Comment: ps: support for ckeditor can also be found from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ckeditor (as the support page of ckeditor suggests)

Comment: The configuration setting can be found in config.js inside the ckeditor directory.

Comment: I found this code config.templates_files = [ '/mytemplates.js' ]; But I dont know how and where I need to use this code.